# default in switch doesn't appear to execute

Tags: arduino-leonardo, avr, switch, compiler

I have a situation where the default case in my switch statement doesn't appear to execute as expected. I wonder if there is some subtlety I'm missing here?

Given the following enum:

```cpp
enum HomingPhase
    {
    Idle = 0,
    Detecting,
    Stopping,
    Reversing,
    AtHome,
    };
```

and the following methods:

```cpp
void HomeSensor::setPhase(HomingPhase newPhase)
    {
    phase = newPhase;
    Serial.print("Phase ");
    Serial.println(phase);
    }

void HomeSensor::onMotorStopped() const
    {
    std::cout << "Hstop " << phase << std::endl;
    switch (phase)
        {
        case Reversing:
            setPhase(AtHome);
            break;
        case Stopping:
            setPhase(Reversing);
            const auto target = commandProcessor.targetStepPosition(homeSettings->position);
            motor->moveToPosition(target);
            break;
        default:
            setPhase(Idle);
            return;
        }
    }
```

At runtime, `onMotorStopped()` is called and I see the following output, which indicates that `phase` is `AtHome` (4) on entry to the method.

> Hstop 4

I expect the default case to execute, setting the phase to `Idle` but I do not see the output from `setPhase()`, which suggests that the default case isn't executing. Subsequent output from elsewhere in the code confirms that `phase` in fact remains set to `AtHome` (4) and isn't being set to `Idle` as expected.

I think I may have gone code blind. Can anyone see the issue?

Comment: One's going to `std::cout` (works). The other to `Serial`. I don't know `std::cout` on an Arduino...  Are you really running it on an Arduino?

Comment: Yes, <ArduinoSTL> works surprisingly well. I should probably change thos to use one or the other and not mix them like that, but the `Serial.println` does produce output in other circumstances so it's not that the print statement isn't working.

Comment: I would try it with Arduino AVR core 1.6.21. Newer have problems

Comment: What happens if you put debug output (either way) on each `case` and `default`?